# Laravel Generic Collections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

My Java experience tells me I can create generic collections like this:

```
Collection<E> collection = new Collection<E>();
```

I am wondering if this is possible in Laravel (at least 5.2+)? I have been using Laravel for nearly 3 years, and have just wondered about this now.

For example, I was thinking of this when creating a Laravel model transformer function as below:

**Current Laravel function:**

```
public function transformMultiple(Collection $models){

        $collection = collect();

        foreach($models as $m){
            $collection->push($this->transform($m));
        }

        return $collection;
    }
```

**Hypothetical function using generics:**

```
public function transformMultiple(Collection<Foo> $models){

        $collection = collect();

        foreach($models as $m){
            $collection->push($this->transform($m));
        }

        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: Php does not have Generics. Maybe this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646397/does-php-have-an-answer-to-java-style-class-generics
Also in the future PHP can provide it: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generics

Comment: @AlexSlipknot Your comment is definitely helpful, and provides the best information I have come across about PHP and Generics. I also got a timely reminder about Liskov substitution, which was an added bonus. If your comment was an answer instead, I'd be tempted at accepting this as a solution.

Comment: Well, thanks :) But it's just an similar question and answer. I think you can just add another or edit existent answer in provided similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With credit to a comment from @AlexSlipKnot, I believe PHP does not currently support Generics; however, [it may support it in the future](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generics). His other link in the comments (a StackOverflow answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646397/does-php-have-an-answer-to-java-style-class-generics)) also provides in-depth guidelines to custom implementations; however, if one is to develop their own custom implementation, they need to beware of applicable [O.O Design Principles](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design).