# PHP equivalent to C++ Templates

Tags: php, c++

In C++, I can create template classes like this:

```
<template class l> class foo {
    private:
    l myVar;

    foo::foo(l var) {
        myVar = var
    }

    l getVar() {
        return myVar
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Can I do something similar in PHP?

Reason I'm asking:

Let's say I have a class in PHP that conceptualizes a MySQL table:

```
class Table {
    private $conn;
    private $name;

    function __construct($connection, $tablename) {
        $this->conn = $connection;
        $this->name = $tablename;
    }
    // etc..
}
```

I can make class functions that handle certain types of queries:

```
    function GetAll() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->name;
        $data = $this->conn->query($sql);

        return $data;
    }
```

Of course, this is just an example, but hopefully you get the picture.

What I'm looking to do is let's say I have a class called "Users". Before I return $data, I would like to put it in a User object. Of course, to be generic, I'd like to be able to put it into ANY class I like. Just like a C++ template.

Note: A PHP interface will not work for this because I'd need to instantiate the class, not just use a given set of functions.

Edit:

So, I [found a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358970/10957435) for MY problem.

However, I'd still like an answer to whether there is a PHP equivalent.

Comment: I'll leave it for more experience member of the community to decide if there's a duplicate here,.  That said, this SO question: may provide some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646397/does-php-have-an-answer-to-java-style-class-generics

Comment: Is this valid PHP code? $var1 = new get_class($var2)(/*params*/);

Comment: Regretfully, I'm not a PHP expert, so I couldn't say for certain.  I found this question while scanning for C++ questions.  The google search that turned up the answer I linked was for "generic programming php".  That search also turned up a number of pages that seem to indicate that the lack of generics in PHP is an issue that's a concern to the community.  "Generics" in this context are the more general name for what C++ calls templates.

Comment: Got you. Thanks for the help. I don't think it's exactly a duplicate because it doesn't solve my exact problem. But it certainly points me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out a work around, but I would still appreciate other answers. I would still like to know if there is a PHP equivalent. However, this is what I've got:

```
class Table {
    private $conn;
    private $name;
    private filter; // a callback

    function __construct($connection, $tablename, $callback) {
        $this->conn = $connection;
        $this->name = $tablename;
        $this->filter = $callback;

    }
    // etc..
}
```

And then in GetAll:

```
    function GetAll() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->name;
        $data = $this->conn->query($sql);

        $data = $this->filter($data);

        return $data;
    }
```

Then, I could pass a callback that filters the data how I want it.

I think that will work.